# NumPy Convert Elements Across Dimensions

Tags: numpy

I have 3d numpy array of the following shape:

```
(3600L, 7200L, 3L)
```

If any element in any dimension is 0, how can I convert the elements in the same position in other two dimensions into 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an element is 0, it is `0 in each of the dimensions`.  I'll illustrate with a small 2d array:

```
In [1240]: M=np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
In [1241]: M
Out[1241]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

In [1242]: M[0,0]
Out[1242]: 0
```

One element is 0, the 0 row and the 0 column.  I can set the rest of those 2 dimensions to 0 with:

```
In [1243]: M[0,:]=0

In [1244]: M[:,0]=0

In [1245]: M
Out[1245]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 4, 5],
       [0, 7, 8]])
```

You can generalize this to 3d and larger arrays.  As long as you know the coordinates of that element in all dimensions.  With a 3d array

```
M[i,:,:]=0
```

actually sets all the values in a plane (2d) to 0.  Similarly for `M[:,j,:]` and `M[:,:,k]`.

---

`np.where` gives the coordinates that match some condition:

```
In [1248]: I=np.where(M==0)

In [1249]: M[I[0],:]=0

In [1250]: M[:,I[1]]=0

In [1251]: M
Out[1251]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 4, 5],
       [0, 7, 8]])

In [1252]: 

In [1252]: I
Out[1252]: (array([0], dtype=int32), array([0], dtype=int32))
```

This works regardless of whether the match is for 1 element, 0, or more.  Here it's just one.

Comment: Ah sorry from your answer I new that i need to change across columns only. Also I did not know to do it programmetically (you knew 0 positions mannually). Can you do it for me?

Comment: I mean how to know where is zero and convert 0 for those locations in other columns as well

Comment: Also I really have a large array, so faster computation is expected

Comment: I added `where` to determine the coordinates.

Comment: Faster than what?    Slice operations like this are as fast as you'll get.